# How do I run artisan migrate in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk env/app?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've done all these [things](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html) to deploy my app but I can't run `php artisan migrate` in the deploy. I've tried many solutions from `container_commands` to `.ebextensions/.platform/hooks` and nothing is working. I even tried to ssh into the ec2 instance and run the migrate command manually but I get errors saying that the connection doesn't work because the env vars aren't set. That led me down a path thinking that I need to login (docker exec ...) to the docker container running on the ec2 instance, but when I try a simple `docker ps` command I get an error saying docker is an unknown command. This is boggling because the aws eb docs say that EB is running docker containers.

At this point i'm at a complete loss. What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here's the error when I ssh into the instance and I run `artisan migrate:status`

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'forge' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE' order by table_name)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:822
    818▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    819▕                 );
    820▕             }
    821▕ 
  ➜ 822▕             throw new QueryException(
    823▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    824▕             );
    825▕         }
    826▕     }

      +35 vendor frames 

  36  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Because the error says `where table_schema = 'forge'` this makes me believe that the env vars is not being set on the bare metal. So I wanted to login to the docker containers but docker is an unknown command.

This is my structure for the platform hooks:
[image]

`01_run_artisan.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/app/staging && pwd && ls -la
```

`02_run_migrations.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/app/staging && php artisan migrate:status
```

I also tried the `container_commands` and that was failing. The error is unknown as the `cfn-init.log` shows:
`[ERROR] Command 01_artisan_migrate (cd /var/app/staging && php artisan migrate:status) failed`

UPDATE:

Here's the errors from the events view:

```
January 10, 2024 13:26:40 (UTC-7)   ERROR   During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
January 10, 2024 13:26:40 (UTC-7)   ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
January 10, 2024 13:26:39 (UTC-7)   ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-xxxxxxxxx'. Aborting the operation.
January 10, 2024 13:26:39 (UTC-7)   INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
January 10, 2024 13:26:39 (UTC-7)   ERROR   [Instance: i-xxxxxxxx] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
January 10, 2024 13:26:36 (UTC-7)   ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'
```

I pulled down the full set of logs and looked at eb-engine.log:
2024/01/10 20:26:36.123454 [INFO] Error occurred during build: Command 01-migration failed
2024/01/10 20:26:36.123478 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [PostBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: Container commands build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.

looking at the cfn-init.log:

```
2024-01-10 20:26:36,088 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2024-01-10 20:26:36,088 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01-migration failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 181, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets, strict_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata, strict_mode).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 567, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 579, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config, self.strict_mode).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 277, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01-migration failed
```

Comment: You need to make sure your deployment is passing correctly as EBS runs through stages; when everything passes, it will finally upload to `/var/app/current`, and this is where your live site is hosted. What's the actual error when you run the migration command when you SSH in and what folder are you doing this command in?

Comment: @Second2None I added the errors and code to the OP

Comment: I've run the suggestion with no luck...see the update I added.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with your `.env` file. Is this present in the staging folder?  If not how are you updating your application code as the file may not be included.

Comment: @Second2None i'm zipping it up and uploading the code. I'm managing the env vars from the configuration in the eb environment.

Comment: From memory I never got those variables to be picked up by Laravel. I ended up pulling my `.env` from a S3 bucket in predeploy. Can take a read of this, it may help expose the variables: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a good way to settle the manual way of setting the env vars and running artisan migrate, but I need an automatic way on deploy to run it.

Comment: @Second2None I guess trying your method of importing the env vars via a script worked. I tried it the first time and didn't work, moved onto something else, came back and tried a second time and voila!

Answer (score 0):

Create the `scripts.config` inside the `.ebextensions` folder.

You can add code as per below inside the `scripts.config`.  It will run automatically when the code is deployed. You can see the logs inside the elastic-beanstalk application as well.

It will show error/success logs.

```
container_commands:
    01-migration:
        command: "php artisan migrate --force"
        leader_only: true
    
    02-migration:
        command: "php artisan db:seed --force"
        leader_only: true

    03-migration:
        command: "php artisan db:seed --class=DefaultFormSeeder --force"
        leader_only: true
```